# How to use the expression given as an argument to generate return of Substitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, nunit, nsubstitute

I have a function that gets some data from a repository and does something with it. I want to test, that the lambda expression is correct, as well as what is done with the data from the repository. So instead of just giving specific data for a given lambda expression through NSubstitute, my idea is to setup a repository (basically a list) with several entries and then test if the lambda expression gets the right data out.

So, this is my Repository:

```
public class SampleRepository : ISampleRepository
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

This is what how it is used:

```
var samples = repository.Get(s => s.Id == id);
// do something with those "samples"
```

This is what I did in the test:

```
var repo = Substitute.For<ISampleRepository>();
var samples = new List<Sample>();
samples.Add(new Sample(1)) // insert sample with id 1
samples.Add(new Sample(2)) // insert sample with id 2
Func<Sample, bool> samplePredicate = null;
repo.Get(Arg.Do<Expression<Func<Sample, bool>>>(arg => samplePredicate = arg.Compile()));
repo.Get(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Sample, bool>>>()).Returns(samples.Where(samplePredicate));
```

This gives me an exception, saying that `samplePredicate` is empty in `.Returns(samples.Where(samplePredicate));`

This makes sense, as at the time the unit under test was not yet called and therefore no argument was given.

However, is there a way to make that work? For example to tell NSubstitute not to execute the `.Where()` on the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should all be done in one expression statement while configuring the expectation on the mocked repo

```
//Arrange
var repo = Substitute.For<ISampleRepository>();
var samples = new List<Sample>();
samples.Add(new Sample(1)) // insert sample with id 1
samples.Add(new Sample(2)) // insert sample with id 2

repo.Get(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Sample, bool>>>())
    .Returns(arg => {
        var predicate = arg.ArgAt<Expression<Func<Mitarbeiter, bool>>>(0).Compile();
        return samples.Where(predicate);            
    });
```